# Bluetooth buffering delay

Tags: bluetooth

I'm running Kubuntu 21.10. At the moment I'm using a Soundcore II Bluetooth portable speaker to play music.  The connection is working, but it frequently pauses for ten seconds or so while the music player displays the message "Buffering .. 0%" What might be going on, and what if anything can I do about it? The speaker is less than a foot away from my laptop, so that should exclude one possible cause.

Comment: Is the message in the speaker itself or in the PC?

Comment: The message shows up in the music player.  I modified the question to reflect that.